# Database Design and Solr

Tags: php, mysql, solr

We have a database of about 500 000 records that has non-normalized data (Vehicles for sale). We have a master MySQL DB and to enable fast searching, we update a Solr index whenever changes are made. Most of our data is served from the Solr index due to the complex nature of the joins and relationships in the MySQL DB.

We have started to run into problems with the speed and integrity of updates from within solr. When we push updates using softcommit we are find that it takes ~1 second for the changes to be visible. While it isn’t a big issue at the moment, we are concerned that the problem will get worse and we want to have a solution before we get there.

We are after some guidance on what solutions we should be looking at:

- How big is our dataset in comparison to other solutions using Solr in
  this manner?
- We are only using 1 server for Solr at the moment. What is the split point to move to clustering and will that help or hinder our update problem?
- One solution we have seen is using a NoSQL DB for some of the
  data. Do NoSQL DBs have better performance on a record by record
  level?
- Are there some other options that might be worth    looking into?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your questions in sequence

1) No your dataset is not that huge. Anything below 1 million records is fine for solr.

2)Using 1 solr server is not a good option. Try SolrCloud, it is the best way to get a solr into High Availability and it will improve your performance

3)Both sql and nosql databases have their advantages and disadvantages. It depends on your dataset. In general nosql databases are faster.

4)I suggest go with SolrCloud.It is fast and reliable.